# RequestMapping не работает, хотя GetMapping или PostMapping работают

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

У меня есть Spring MVC приложение, когда я заменяю @GetMapping("/addPhoto") на RequestMapping(name = "/addPhoto",method = RequestMethod.GET) у мене просто не стратует программа

> [2019-01-28 07:01:26,525] Artifact tests:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details

Форма

```
  <html>
 <head>
<title>File uploading</title>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/addPhoto" method="post">
     <input type="file" name="photo" >
     <input type="submit"  value="Go!"  >
 </form>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Контроллеры:

```
 @RequestMapping(name = "/addPhoto",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPhoto(){
    return "uploadAFile";
}
@RequestMapping(name = "/addPhoto", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String gg(@RequestParam("photo") MultipartFile file){
    return "redirect:/addPhoto";
}
```

Это еще не все, даже если я заменю RequestMapping на PostMapping и GetMapping форма просто не будет отправлять параметр "photo". Из-за чего не работает RequestMapping и как исправить проблему с параметрами, заранее спасибо.

Comment: See server log for details

Comment: И где же их взять ?

Comment: Смотря какой сервер используете.

Comment: 7 томкат использую

Comment: Ищите каталог `logs` или в месте установки Tomcat или где-нибудь в `/var`.

Comment: Щас посмеетесь, не работало потому что у меня в RequestMapping в параметрах вместо value стоит name

Comment: @ggff я только хотел это написать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте наличие в контексте сервлета бина типа `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver`.

Comment: Бина не было, я добавил но проблема осталась. Адресная строка при нажатии на submit вообще никак не меняется, а Tomcat ругается, что нету параметра photo

Comment: Вообщем, переписал кое-что (настройки диспетчера и тело пост контроллера) отсюда https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/file-upload-servlet-resolver.html и вуаля, оно заработало, в любом случае спасибо, что помогли :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить:

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/addPhoto", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

На:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addPhoto", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: Да, я понял уже, спасибо